# calling a host function from a global kernel

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I'm trying to call a function from a kernel and I keep getting errors. My function is a template argument. 
Here is the error:

```
 calling a __host__ function("mul<int> ") from a __global__ function("multiply<int, &mul<int> > ") is not allowed.
```

Here is my code:

```
    template<typename T> T mul(T a, T b)
{
    return a * b;
}
template <typename T, T (*myop)(T, T)>
static __global__ void multiply(int *in, int *out)
{...
 a = myop(b, c);
 ...
}
int main()
{
multiply<T, mul<T> ><<<Blocks, 1024>>>(...);
}
```

Does somebody know what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that are intended to be used in device code must have the `__device__` [qualifier](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-type-qualifiers):

```
$ cat t1018.cu
#include <stdio.h>
template<typename T>
__host__ __device__ T mul(T a, T b)
{
    return a * b;
}

template <typename T, T (*myop)(T, T) >
static __global__ void multiply()
{
 T b=2;
 T c=5;
 T a = myop(b, c);
 printf("a = %d\n", a);

}
int main()
{
  multiply<int, mul<int> ><<<1, 1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t1018 t1018.cu
$ ./t1018
a = 10
$
```

Comment: I just have a question, why did you add __ host __? __ device __ is not good enough?

Comment: For your example, `__device__` is good enough.  I added `__host__` because according to your original example it was a host function, and it's possible in your actual code you might also have been using that somewhere else in host code (that you hadn't shown).  By adding the `__host__` qualifier, we would not break that usage (if you were possibly using it that way also).  But for the extent of this example, you could delete `__host__`.